# How to build a dynamic PLSQL query to fetch records?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle and make a dynamic query work to get a bunch of records. I have read many examples but so far I can't get this to work unless I do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GiveMeResultSet(
    v_par1  IN CHAR,
    v_par2  IN CHAR,
    v_par3  IN CHAR,
    v_par4  IN VARCHAR2,
    v_par5  IN VARCHAR2,
    v_par6  IN VARCHAR2,
    cur_typ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_typ FOR 'select * from complex_query';   
  --CLOSE cur_typ;
END;
```

And I am executing it this way:

```
var c refcursor;
execute GiveMeResultSet(null,null,null,null,null,null,:c);
print c;
```

This way I get the header names and the records from the query, but I am not closing the cursor that is fetching the results. If I close it then I get nothing at all. I guess leaving it open could cause some kind of memory leak problem at some point.

I have seen similar cases in Oracle documentation where they do something like this:

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp';
   OPEN emp_cv FOR sql_stmt;
   LOOP
      FETCH emp_cv INTO emp_rec;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cv%NOTFOUND;
      -- process record
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE emp_cv;
```

But I have no clue what goes on the `"process record"` part of the code which would allow to get the whole set of records at the end, plus that my record has a complex structure that doesn't fit with a fixed set of fields as in a table.

Can you please show me the proper way to do this?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1606716582692) article explains about "Closing Ref Cursors"

Answer (score 1):

ok CodeRoller, here is my sample code for a unspecified ref cursor:

Code of the Function which returns the ref cursor:

```
create or replace function test_ref_cursor(pi_sql_statement in varchar2) return  SYS_REFCURSOR is
  result_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin

  open result_cursor for pi_sql_statement;

  return result_cursor;

end;
```

Now, in the next step I use this function to get data from v$parameter:

```
declare
  type t_my_cursor is ref cursor;
  my_cursor t_my_cursor;

  l_rec v$parameter%rowtype;
begin

  my_cursor := test_ref_cursor('select * from v$parameter');

  loop
     fetch my_cursor into l_rec;
     exit when my_cursor%notfound;


     dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.name || ' = ' || l_rec.value);


  end loop;


  close my_cursor;

end;
```

Take care, to close the ref-cursor!